# Weird Sleeping Hours

Tags: sleep

I tried following some advice at [a productivity question about sleeping hours](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/2268/at-what-time-do-early-risers-go-to-sleep-at-night), so I woke up at 4 am for three days straight and by 10 am (!) I feel sleepy that I can't open my eyes. I usually go to bed at 9 pm so I think that's a healthy lifestyle.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a sleep cycle, especially drastically, takes time for you body to adjust to. It's pretty self induced jetlag and you're trying to yank your entire circadian rhythm to another setup. According to [webmd](http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/excessive-sleepiness-10/jet-lag-remedies), and [answers on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-typically-take-to-recover-from-jet-lag), jetlag can last 4-5 days, but varies by person and time adjustment. (Three days was almost there!)

Your circadian rhythm, sleep playing a large part, entails a lot of aspects, all which need to adjust to a different sleep schedule. Consider how your eating, exercise, and the rest of your daily rhythm comes into play.

Lastly, consider using other sleep hacks to help adjust. Searching for adjusting to jetlag will provide plenty of tips. Here's a really long answer I wrote on Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange on [sleep hacks](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/7917/2893).

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'm starting to get used to the new schedule. As of eating, I eat just enough to continue breathing. No, really, I don't much enjoy food. For exercise, I do sports about 7~8 hours a week. But most of my days are just behind a computer screen, which I think is the root of my sleeping habits. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: This has the makings of a decent answer, but here on Health, we strongly encourage using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources